# How to input a string with unknown size

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, scanf

I'm a bit confused about strings in C. I understand that declaring buffer size is important since otherwise, it can cause buffer overflow. But I need to know how do I take a string input that I don't know the size of. For instance, if I wanted  to take a line of text from the user as input and I had no way of knowing how long their text would be, how do I do it?

I've tried dynamically allocating memory as the user gives an input. Here's the code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str, ch;
    int size = 10, len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
    if (!str)return str;
    while (EOF != scanf_s("%c", &ch) && ch != '\n')
    {
        str[len++] = ch;
        if (len == size)
        {
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size += 10));
            if (!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
}
```

The problem is, when I compile it using VS-2017, I get these errors-

> source.c(10): warning C4473: 'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed
>   for format string
>
> source.c(10): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 2
>   variadic arguments, but 1 were provided
>
> source.c(10): note: the missing variadic argument 2 is required by
>   format string '%c'
>
> source.c(10): note: this argument is used as a buffer size

I think that dynamically allocating memory as I go on(like in the above code) should work, but I'm probably doing something wrong. Is there a way to make this work?

EDIT: Word.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` here but rather `getc`.

Comment: And don't use `scanf_s()` or any of the other `*_s()` functions from Annex K of the C standard.  They're no more secure than standard C functions if the standard ones are used properly, [and the `*_s()` functions are not portable as implemented by Microsoft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1967.htm): "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should use `getchar` not `scanf_s`
2. You should use `int ch;` not `char ch;` for `EOF`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str = NULL;
    int ch;
    size_t size = 0, len = 0;

    while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (len + 1 >= size)
        {
            size = size * 2 + 1;
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*size);
        }
        str[len++] = ch;
    }
    if (str != NULL) {
        str[len] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str);
        free(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `size` and `len` should be `size_t` not `int`. Also `realloc()` might fail.

Comment: @Yunbin Liu can you please tell me why are we checking len+1 >= size and why we are updating size = size *2 + 1. Please do tell me I am unable to understand that part

Answer (score 2):

- `scanf_s` requires a buffer size as argument, and you don't want that
- Generally `scanf` will read from `stdin` once the `\n` is fed anyways.
- Using `getchar` here is a better approach

Here is a version using `getchar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main()
{
  char  *str = NULL;
  int   ch;
  int   capacity = 10, size = 0;

  str = realloc(str, sizeof(*str) * (capacity + 1));
  if (!str) return 1;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
      if (size == capacity)
      {
        capacity += 10;
        str = realloc(str, sizeof(*str) * (capacity + 1));
        if (!str) return 1;
      }
      str[size] = (char)ch;
      size++;
    }
  str[size] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", str);
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Being picky: `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition, so just drop it. Or if you intend to provide code being robust against changes of `str`'s type then use `sizeof *str` instead.

Comment: First call to `realloc(str)` might be problematic since `str` is never initialized. Also, `size == capacity` is not good enough since you need an additional space for the ending nul-character.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed that part, although it will still fail for an empty string, i.e. when you never enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf_s` requires an additional "buffer-size" parameter for each formatted input place holder. That's what your compiler complains. So when using `scanf_s`, you'd have to write `scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1)`. But you could simply use `scanf` as well, as you can guarantee that your buffer `ch` is large enough to take on a character value in any case. So `scanf("%c",&ch)` will work securely as well.

Note further that `scanf` (and `scanf_s`) return the number of values correctly read in; A return value of `0` would be possible as well, also indicating that nothing was read in.

So I'd test it as ...

```
while (scanf("%c", &ch)==1 && ch != '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost fine.

Two things should be changed:

1. don't use `scanf` but use `getc`
2. `ch` should be `int`, otherwise the comparision with `EOF` will cause trouble.
3. Nitpicking detail: `main` should return 0 in case of success and a value different from 0 in case of failure.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *str;
  int ch;
  int size = 10, len = 0;

  str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
  if (str == NULL)
    return 1;

  while ( (ch = getc(stdin)) && ch != EOF && ch != '\n')
  {
    str[len++] = (char)ch;

    if (len == size)
    {
      str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size += 10));

      if (str == NULL)
        return 1;
    }
  }

  str[len] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", str);
  free(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *The problem is, when I compile it using VS-2017, I get these errors-*
>
> ```
> source.c(10): warning C4473: 'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
>
> source.c(10): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 2 variadic arguments, but 1 were provided
>
> source.c(10): note: the missing variadic argument 2 is required by format string '%c'
>
> source.c(10): note: this argument is used as a buffer size
> ```

The warning and notes are quite explicit, aren't they?

Looking up [the related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017) reveals under the "Remarks" section:

> Unlike **scanf** and **wscanf**, **scanf_s** and **wscanf_s** require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type **c**, **C**, **s**, **S**, or string control sets that are enclosed in **[]**. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So you want to change

```
  while (EOF != scanf_s("%c", &ch) && ch != '\n')
```

to look at least like this:

```
  while (EOF != scanf_s("%c", &ch, sizeof ch) && ch != '\n')
```

even better would be to provide complete error checking like this:

```
  {
    int result;
    while (1 == (result = scanf_s("%c", &ch, sizeof ch)) 
           && ch != '\n')
    {
      ...
    }

    if (EOF == result && ferror(stdin)) /* As scanf'ing uses stdin, 
                                           test its error status. */
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "scanf_s() failed.\n")
    }
  }
```